# Screen Options in wordpress is not working for new custom meta box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have created a meta box named "My Custom Settings", it is under post in wordpress with one input text box field. In the above to that post page I have seen the screen options menu with predefined "show on screen". After adding my new "My custom settings" meta box, it also available in that screen options.

I have just hide that "My custom settings". But still it seems under post.

Why its not hiding when hide on screen options?

My code is,

```
<?php
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'meta_add_custom_box' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'meta_save_custom_meta_box' );
function meta_add_custom_box( $post ) {
add_meta_box(
'Meta Box', // ID, should be a string
'My Custom Settings', // Meta Box Title
'meta_custom_meta_box_content', // Your call back function, this is where your form field will go
'post', // The post type you want this to show up on, can be post, page, or custom post type
'normal', // The placement of your meta box, can be normal or side
'high' // The priority in which this will be displayed
);
}

function meta_save_custom_meta_box(){
global $post;
// Get our form field
if( $_POST ) :
$meta_custom_meta = esc_attr( $_POST['meta-custom-meta-box'] );
// Update post meta
update_post_meta($post->ID, '_meta_custom_meta', $meta_custom_meta);
endif;
}

function meta_custom_meta_box_content( $post ) {
$meta_custom_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_meta_custom_meta', true);
//meta title with character counting
echo '<p><label>Custom Title:</label></p>';
echo '<p><input style="width:99%;" class="meta-text" type="text" name="meta-custom-meta-box" value="'.$meta_custom_meta.'" /></p>';
}
?>
```

Whether I need to add extra code for screen options to hide?? 
If yes please update my code.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 add_filter('default_hidden_meta_boxes', 'hide_meta_lock', 10, 2);
 function hide_meta_lock($hidden, $screen) {
if ( 'frog' == $screen->base )
    $hidden = array('postexcerpt','Meta Box');
    // removed 'postexcerpt',
return $hidden;
 }
```